# UIview using pointInside method

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating a UIview and applying a mask on it in this way:

```
baseView = [[ViewTutorialSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
//self.view = baseView;
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
[baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
baseView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
baseView.alpha = 0.7;

mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
mask.frame = baseView.layer.bounds;
CGRect biggerRect = CGRectMake(mask.frame.origin.x, mask.frame.origin.y, mask.frame.size.width, mask.frame.size.height);
CGRect smallerRect = CGRectMake(7.0f, 160.0f, 590.0f, 43.0f);

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];

[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];

mask.path = maskPath.CGPath;
[mask setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
mask.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
baseView.layer.mask = mask;
```

In my ViewTutorialSubclass.m I have:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
    CGPoint localPoint = [v convertPoint:point fromView:self];
    if (v.alpha > 0.8 && [v pointInside:localPoint withEvent:event])
        return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

The idea is that all user touches are passed to the UIview below this one if the user touches any part of the UIview with the mask (so transparent), while if the user touches anywhere else, the touches are applied to this current UIview. How can I don that? Is pointInside the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class of the view that contains the mask layer should override pointInside and return YES or NO based on the state of mask.  If the mask is always going to be a rectangle then you can do a point in rectangle test, but I bet that's not what you want.  You want this test to work for an arbitrarily shaped mask.  Set up (in a dispatch_once) a one pixel wide CGBitmapContext.  In pointInside:withEvent: render the mask layer into the bitmap context and see if it drew anything.  Here's an example:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    static CGContextRef context;
    static CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace;
    static unsigned char bitmapData[4];
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, 1, 1, 8, 4, rgbColorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    });
    if ([super pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);
        [self.layer.mask renderInContext:context];
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, point.x, point.y);
        BOOL result = (bitmapData[3] > 0);
        memset(bitmapData, 0, sizeof(bitmapData));
        return result;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

**Edit:** The compiler in Xcode 5 generates a warning about the enumerated type mismatch if you pass kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast (on its own) to `CGBitmapContextCreate`.  The type of the argument is supposed to be `CGBitmapInfo` but `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` is from the enumerated type `CGImageAlphaInfo`.  To eliminate the warning you can combine `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` with a value from the `CGBitmapInfo` enumerated type, like `kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`.  It's better this way anyway because the new code makes it explicit that we're sending general "bitmap info," but we're interested *only* in bitmap info related to how the alpha channel is handled.

Comment: The answer looks great. You have understood right, I will at some point remove the mask and add another one with different sizes, but I can't really understand your approach to the problem

Comment: @Alessandro The code in the dispatch_once creates a drawing context backed by a one pixel bitmap.  The later code applies a transform to the bitmap context that takes point to the origin and draws the mask into the bitmap.  If point is in the transparent mask then a transparent pixel, {0, 0, 0, 0}, will be drawn at the origin.  If point is not in the mask a black full alpha pixel, {0, 0, 0, 255}, will be drawn at the origin.  The bitmap pixels are stored in bitmapData and the alpha component is the fourth byte, bitmapData[3].